# Multi Database on Drupal

Tags: database, drupal

I have to implement a system that contain multi-sites using Drupal. ( expected 1000 sites)
Drupal allow us to use multi databases or one database with prefix.
With thousands of sites, I may choose multi databases instead of one database with prefix. And All databases have same table structure. 
But the problem is :
There are some very **frequently** query that collect information from all sites ( all databases).
For example: Select 20 products have category is Shoes and has good voting rate  from all databases.
I have 3 solutions right now :

1. Use a for loop to select databases . it means 1000 query "Select * from db1.table1 where category=123 and vote=10"; And then choose matching product. I think that's worse in performance because there are so much memory used if there are many rows in all databases.
2. Use Select * FROM db1.table1 .... UNION SELECT * FROM db2.table1 ....... I think that's bad too. Because mysql will choose from db1 first, if there is enough 20 products, mysql will stop finding.
3. Whenever inserting to all database, we insert into a very large database with a site flag. So that, we can do select query from this very large databases using a simple query :  "SELECT * FROM largeDB.table WHERE category=123 and vote=10".

Please give me more advices . Thank you very much. 
P.S: And please tell me more about problems with database maintain when I have 1000s same databases.

Comment: Anyone please give me advices. Thank you very much

Comment: Would probably help you get an answer if you added your specific database as a tag (e.g., mysql). Nothing about the question seems especially Drupal-oriented.

Comment: Yes this is very confusing... does each database hold site specific related data or are you just splitting the product types(from what I get) into separate databases? Is there one site or multiple sites?

Answer (score 1):

I just want to make sure you are aware of Drupal's out-of-the-box multisite functionality? All you have to do is make a new folder in the sites folder, and either create a symbolic link to it and/or add it to the sites.php (which may or may not work depending on server).

Sorry if you already knew this, wanted to make sure you don't custom do a solution if this will work for you. It handles multiple sites with their own databases on a single Drupal install quite well. Unfortunately I can't help with the multiple database queries from a single site, in the past I have just done so with a manual PHP query.